# Show we can assume algebra of compact operators can be assumed to have trivial nullspace.

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras

In the book "Invitation to $C^*$-algebras" by Arveson, I read that:

Let $\mathcal{A}$ be a $C^*$-subalgebra of $B_0(\mathcal{H})$ (= compact operators on the Hilbert space $\mathcal{A}$). The book then reads:

> By cutting down to an $\mathcal{A}$-invariant subspace, if necessary,
>   we may assume that $\mathcal{A}$ has trivial null-space.

What exactly does this mean and how can we achieve it?

I think it means that we can find a subspace $\mathcal{K} \leq \mathcal{H}$ such that $T\xi \in \mathcal K$ for all $\xi \in \mathcal{K}$ and for all $T \in \mathcal{A}$ and that the restricted operators $T\vert_\mathcal{K}: \mathcal{K} \to \mathcal{K}$ have trivial nullspace, i.e. the common intersection of all their kernels is $0$.

Is this interpretation correct? And how can we prove such subspace exists?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The space is $$\mathcal K=\overline{\{A\xi:\ A\in\mathcal A,\ \xi\in \mathcal H\}}.$$
It is obviously invariant for $\mathcal A$. And, for any $A\in\mathcal A$, if $A\ne0$ there exists $\xi$ such that $A\xi\ne0$. Then $A^*(A\xi)\ne0$ (since $\ker A^*A=\ker A$). So the intersection of the kernels of all elements in $\mathcal A$ is $\{0\}$.

Comment: Thanks! I don't see though how this implies we can WLOG assume that our original space $\mathcal{A}$ has trivial nullspace?

Comment: Because you want to work with $\mathcal A$, and you think of it as restricted to $\mathcal K$.

Comment: Basically, if you decompose with respect to $\mathcal K$, you have that $$\mathcal A=\begin{bmatrix} \mathcal A_0&0\\0&0\end{bmatrix}.$$ For most practical aspects, you can work with $\mathcal A_0$ instead of $\mathcal A$.

Comment: Makes sense! Thanks again!

Comment: I have another question which you might be able to answer! https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3622381/how-is-this-summation-of-c-representations-interpreted