# How is this summation of $C^*$-representations interpreted?

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras

I'm reading the book "Invitation to $C^*$-algebras" by Arveson and I'm focused on understanding the summation as defined here:

[image]

Can someone explicitely describe what the map $\sum_i \pi_i$ does? Since it is a representation of $A$, the domain should be $A$ and since it is a subrepresentation of $\pi$, the codomain should be $B(\mathcal{H}')$ for some subspace $\mathcal{H}' \leq \mathcal{H}$. Where is the orthogonality condition necessary?

Comment: Which book are you reading?

Comment: "An invitation to $C^*$-algebras" by Arveson. This is on p19, but I made some changes in how it is written there to make the post more self-contained.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The map, as you say, is $a\longmapsto \sum_j\pi_j(a)$. Since the $\{\mathcal H_j\}$ are pairwise orthogonal, you have no convergence issues (because $\|\sum_j T_j\|=\sup\{\|T_j\|:\ j\}$ if $T_j\in B(\mathcal H_j)$; it is essential that the subspaces are pairwise orthogonal).

If you want to emphasize the view of $\sum_j\pi_j$ as a subrepresentation, the codomain is $B(\bigoplus_j\mathcal H_j)$.

What you are doing in spirit is defining 
$$
\left(\sum_j\pi_j\right)(a):=(\pi_j(a))_{j\in I}.
$$
The norm is the supremum, i.e., 
$$
\|(\pi_j(a))_{j\in I}\|=\sup\{\|\pi_j(a)\|:\ j\in I\}, 
$$
so everything works fine. If you had just a couple, what you are doing is 
$$
\left(\pi_1+\pi_2\right)(a):=\begin{bmatrix} \pi_1(a)&0\\0&\pi_2(a)\end{bmatrix}. 
$$

Comment: Thanks! Where does the orthogonality kick in?

Comment: And how is this a subrepresentation of $\pi$? What is the subspace of $\mathcal{H}$ here?

Comment: If the subspaces are not orthogonal, it is hard to say when $\sum_j\pi_j(a)$ would converge; plus you wouldn't get a representation.

Comment: In your question you didn't relate the $\pi_j$ to $\pi$. If one thinks of them as $\pi_j=\pi|_{\mathcal H_j}$, then they are subrepressentations because that's precisely the definition of subrepresentation.

Comment: But it looks like you get a map $A \to \prod_{i \in I} B(\mathcal{H}_i)$? In the book, it says that $\sum_i \pi_i$ is a subrepresentation of $\pi$. Don't I need the codomain to be $B(\mathcal{H}')$ where $\mathcal{H}'$ is some subspace?

Comment: Since the $\mathcal H_j$ are pairwise orthogonal, $\prod_jB(\mathcal H_j)$ embeds canonically in $B(\mathcal H)$.

Comment: What is the canonical embedding? Where do we send $(T_j)_j?$

Comment: To the operator that acts as $T_j$ on $\mathcal H_j$. There nothing more canonical than that.

Comment: But how does it act  in the complement of these $\mathcal{H}_j$'s?

Comment: On the complement of $\bigoplus_j\mathcal H_j$? As zero, what else?

Comment: It looks like it suffices that the spaces have trivial intersections rather than are pairwise orthogonal? Is that correct?

Comment: I also don't see how you can make the operator $0$ without destroying linearity.

Comment: No. If they have just trivial intersection, you cannot guarantee that you get a bounded operator, as you have no way to calculate the norm.

Comment: Hi, sorry I'm kinda desparate to understand this. I edited my question to make my question clear. I will add a bounty as soon as I can and award it to you if you are able to help. Thanks.

Comment: I have added a couple paragraphs. You don't really need a bounty.

Comment: But can you explicitely write down what $\sum_i \pi_i(a)$ does? This should be a linear operator $\bigoplus_j \mathcal{H}_j \to \bigoplus_j \mathcal{H}_j$, so what does it do to $\sum_j \xi_j$ where $\xi_j \in \mathcal{H}_j$?

Comment: $$\left(\sum_j\pi_j(a)\right)\sum_j\xi_j=\sum_j\pi_j(a)\xi_j.$$

Comment: Okay perfect! And now why does that converge?

Comment: Because $\|\pi_j(a)\|\leq\|a\|$, so $$\left\|\sum_j\pi_j(a)\xi_j\right\|^2=\sum_j\|\pi_j(a)\xi_j\|^2\leq\|a\|^2\,\sum_j\|\xi_j\|^2. $$

Comment: Thanks so much (for your patience)! I think I finally get it.

Comment: Nice. $\ \ \ \ \ $